# Store calculations within select statement (postgres)

Tags: postgresql, select, stored-procedures, calculated-columns

I want to run a query like the following:

```
select
  sqrt(pow(sin(foo), 2)) + sqrt(1 - pow(sin(foo), 2)) as calc_value
from mytable
```

This is easy if I don't mind repeating the `pow(sin(foo))` (which in reality is a far more complicated calculation). How do I store the result of this call (and other calls), like this (psuedo-code):

```
select
  (
    a = pow(sin(foo))
    return sqrt(a) + sqrt(1 - a)
  ) as calc_value
from mytable
```

I know I could use sub-queries, but for this application I want to avoid that.

I also know that I could write a stored procedure, but if possible I would like to avoid that too.

Thanks.

Comment: *"I know I could use sub-queries, but for this application I want to avoid that."* So.. you don't want to use the tool in your toolbox that is built for this job? Why? Is it the syntax? Perhaps a CTE would be more to your liking?

Comment: What is a CTE? The reason I don't want to use subqueries is because for the application at hand, it is necessary to integrate this with sequelize (not my personal choice), and not using subqueries makes it a lot simpler.

Comment: Can you create a view in your database and then point sequelize at that? I've not worked with sequelize, so the need to avoid subqueries makes sense. A CTE isn't going to help in that case since it's more of a restriction/complication on your application codebase.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a lateral function join:

```sql
SELECT sqrt(a) + sqrt(1 - a) AS calc_value
FROM mytable, pow(sin(foo), 2) AS a;
```

Online example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=de5e492db3476d3d055e9bfc2e917414

I don't think there will be another solution usable with sequelize without fall back to raw queries.

It's your decision: execution performance vs. ease of code in sequelize.

Comment: I ended up writing a stored function as that is the easiest approach in my case.